# INSERT INTO missing syntax?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm coming across an odd problem with INSERT INTO. Trying to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Claims_temp (CLAIM_NO)
SELECT CLAIM_NO AS CLAIM_FACT
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE CLAIM_NO LIKE "*-*"
UNION 
SELECT "L" & CLAIM_NO AS CLAIM_FACT
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE CLAIM_NO NOT LIKE "*-*";
```

I get this error: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CLAIM_NO LIKE "*-*" UNION SELECT "L" & CLAIM_NO AS CLAIM_FACT FROM CLAIMS WHERE CLAIM_NO NOT LIKE "*-*"'.

If I remove the `INSERT INTO Claims_temp` line, then the query runs and produces the correct results. I can't see any syntax errors. I've also tried specifying the tables, i.e. instead of using CLAIM_NO I use CLAIMS.CLAIM_NO in the select query portion.

Comment: @GurV, I think in access `*` is used instead of ANSI `%`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem still persists with these changes. Further, the query results are incorrect with the % operator rather than *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a strange approach.  Why not just do:

```
INSERT INTO Claims_temp (CLAIM_NO)
    SELECT IIF(CLAIM_NO LIKE "*-*", CLAIM_NO, "L" & CLAIM_NO) AS CLAIM_FACT
    FROM CLAIMS;
```

If there could be duplicates (which the `UNION` removes), then use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Hey, this is great! Sorry for the strange approach, I'm still fairly new to SQL so some of the syntax is not familiar to me (IIF, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think Gordon's answer is correct but I want to add a supplement explaining why.

The error suggests that the SQL parser cannot make sense of the statement but the problem seems to be only there when the insert line is added.

That suggests that the parser is treating `INSERT ... SELECT`  as a syntax distinct from `SELECT` and therefore the `UNION` may not be supportable in the normal pipeline.

If that doesn't work for you I would try an inline view.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Claims_temp (CLAIM_NO)
SELECT claim_fact FROM (
SELECT CLAIM_NO AS CLAIM_FACT
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE CLAIM_NO LIKE "*-*"
UNION 
SELECT "L" & CLAIM_NO AS CLAIM_FACT
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE CLAIM_NO NOT LIKE "*-*") AS foo;
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to avoid sub-queries as much as possible because they tend to break Access for me.

Comment: They also make code hard to read.  So again, Gordon's answer is best.   But hopefully this sheds some light on why it is happening :-)

Comment: Definitely! Thanks again!